# Agendar horario de paciente de 30 em 30 minutos e guardar no banco mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Boa noite preciso fazer uma agenda de marcação de consulta de uma clínica médica em `C#`. Preciso listar o horário de atendimento de 30 em 30 minutos, e guardar apenas o horário da consulta marcada no banco de dados *MySQL*. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Comment: Coloca a parte do script que já tens pronta.

Comment: O que você já fez? Onde está com problemas?